# Error:The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the RecordType.Id field

Tags: workflow, error, record-type

I am trying to write a workflow that fires when a record type is changed to another type in the Contact Object.

I saw a similar question asked, and I tried that solution, but still got the same error. I have tried RecordType.Name and RecordType.Id with the same resulting error message.

This is what I have so far:

```
IF(  ISCHANGED(  RecordType.Id  ),
 IF(  CONTAINS( RecordType.Id , "Contact"),False)
)
```

Thanks!
Carmen

Comment: @DavidReed Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISCHANGED can't go through relationships, but you can can check `RecordTypeId` instead (note: no dot). The latter part doesn't matter, either, so you can probably just write:

```
ISCHANGED(RecordTypeId)
```